# PHP Forms - Numeric Value of Checkbox

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I am creating an online order form for multiple products. I need to calculate the total cost for the products selected via checkbox and send it as a confirmation e-mail. The value of the checkbox is the price in dollars.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="product1" name="product1" value="100" />
<input type="checkbox" id="product2" name="product2" value="250" />
```

In my 'process.php' file, I need to total the cost for all items if they are checked.

```
if(isset($_POST['product1']) && $_POST['product1'] == '100') {
    $product1 = 100;
}

if(isset($_POST['product2']) && $_POST['product2'] == '250') {
    $product2 = 250;
}

$dollars = $product1 + $product2;
```

When I try to do it this way, $dollars is an empty variable "". Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure you are passing the values to process.php? Are you submitting a form with `method="post"`?

Comment: If you add `print_r($_POST);` are you getting a populated POST array?

Comment: Are u sure, that $_POST['product1'] and $_POST['product2'] are set correctly?

Comment: @Travesty3 Yes. There are many other fields in this form that are passing their values fine.

Comment: If a checkbox is not checked, the key will not be set on the receiving end. Make sure the method on the form is `post` and that the checkboxes are indeed checked.

Comment: Why are you using the values in the first place. It looks like I can order your stuff really cheap this way.

Comment: @PeeHaa I agree, there are some big problems with handling an order form this way (what if he sells two products that are both $100?), but they're not relevant to the OP's issue. I assume he'll take care of the rest later on.

Comment: @octern I've been long enough here on SO to assume nothing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntactical error in your code. So the only explanation is that,

1. $_POST['product1'] does not have value `100` or they are not sent through post at all
2. $_POST['product2'] also does not have value `250` or they are not sent through post as well

In order to verify this, do a quick `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of your .php file

Comment: Embarrassingly enough, I made a capitalization typo in the 'process.php' file that I didn't carry over when I retyped here. The code above does indeed work. Thank you!

Comment: @PatrickAppelman, Its really Ok, it happens to the best of us. All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

This works, so something does not work in your code but we cant see it right now

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    if(isset($_POST['product1']) && $_POST['product1'] == '100') {
        $product1 = 100;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['product2']) && $_POST['product2'] == '250') {
        $product2 = 250;
    }

    echo $dollars = $product1 + $product2;

}
?>

<form method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" id="product1" name="product1" value="100" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="product2" name="product2" value="250" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post an array of checkbox if you want. Try this :

```
<?php

$dollars = 0;

// If the user post the form
if(isset($_POST['value'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['product'] as $product) {
        if(is_numeric($product) && $product >= 0) {
            $dollars += $product;
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>Product : <?php echo $dollars; ?></p>

        <form method="post">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="100" /> 100</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="250" /> 250</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="350" /> 350</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="20" /> 20</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="25" /> 25</label><br/>

            <input type="submit" name="value" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code gets an array of selected products and make the sum.

Answer (score -2):

Checkbox values are not sent to the server with POST data if not checked. (edited post)

If you must POST this data, consider using a `<input type="hidden" name="product1value" value="100"/>` to send the value instead? Keep the check boxes just to see if they are ticked.

Comment: Checkbox values are sent as long as the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Also, this won't solve the problem because hidden values are always "on." The user can't indicate whether or not they want the product.

Comment: I was suggest using hidden values with the checkboxes, not instead of.